# Syntax When Combining dd and pv

Tags: shell, pipe, dd, pv

In :

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda bs=64k | pv --size 1.5t | dd of=/dev/sdb
```

Does the block size for dd go on the left side of this after the input as shown or on the right after the output?

With the pipe viewer size option, is it correct that there is no equals sign before the value?  Is it okay to use a decimal value as shown above?

Answer (score 9):

A number of issues that might benefit from review.

> ```
> sudo dd if=/dev/sda bs=64k | pv --size 1.5t | dd of=/dev/sdb
> ```

Firstly, you can (vastly) increase the block size and correspondingly increase the throughput. I often use `bs=32M`. The order of the parameters to `dd` does not matter, so:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda bs=1M
```

Next, it doesn't matter whether you specify `--size` with or without an equals. Long args (those starting with a double dash) usually aren't fussy. However, a quick try out of `pv` shows that the argument must be an integer. So:

```
pv --size 1500g
```

Finally, it would be worth specifying a large (output) buffer for `dd`, and you'll probably need to run it with root privileges. Because we are using a large buffer it's worth ensuring we have filled it completely before trying to write it out. So you end up with this:

```
sudo dd of=/dev/sdb bs=1M iflag=fullblock
```

Putting it all together,

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda bs=1M | pv --size 1500g | sudo dd of=/dev/sdb bs=1M iflag=fullblock
```

I should really point out, though, that on Linux-based systems there's no need to use `dd` for copying from/to disk drives. On this basis the whole command chain can be simplified to just this,

```
sudo sh -c 'pv --skip-errors --size 1500g </dev/sda >/dev/sdb'
```

Comment: @sudodus that's nothing to do with the question as asked. However there are a number of solutions here that address sync/flush times

Comment: Thanks, I found and tested `blockdev --flushbufs /dev/sdx` to flush a single device