# compressing and decompressing dd image - zstd instead of gzip

Tags: command-line, dd, compression, zstd

Earlier I was using fsarchiver to create compressed partition image. Due to some [weird behavior](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/492749/206574) I am choosing to replace it with `dd`.

However, I like how fsarchiver compressed with [zstd](http://www.fsarchiver.org/compression/).

So, I studied,

- [How to make a disk image and restore from it later?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19901/how-to-make-a-disk-image-and-restore-from-it-later)
- [Using DD for disk cloning](https://serverfault.com/questions/4906/using-dd-for-disk-cloning)
- [Making full disk image with DD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509639/making-full-disk-image-with-dd)
- [compressing dd backup on the fly](https://serverfault.com/questions/52260/compressing-dd-backup-on-the-fly)
- [How do you monitor the progress of dd?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/215505/how-do-you-monitor-the-progress-of-dd)

What these essentially say is, I have to use the following command to backup

```
dd if=/dev/sda2 status=progress | gzip -c > /media/mint/Data/_Fsarchiver/MintV1.img.gz
```

And the following command to restore

```
gunzip -c /media/mint/Data/_Fsarchiver/MintV1.img.gz | dd of=/dev/sda2 status=progress
```

Now I want to replace `gzip -c` & `gunzip -c` with `zstd` & `zstd -d`

The commands I came up with are

To compress

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda2 status=progress | zstd -16vT6 > /media/mint/Data/_Fsarchiver/MintV1.zst
```

To decompress

```
zstd -vdcfT6 /media/mint/Data/_Fsarchiver/MintV1.zst | dd of=/dev/sda2 status=progress
```

Is it safe to try these commands or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Using `dd` like that (without any options) will make your life miserable. Just cut it out entirely. Or at the very least increase its block size and tell it not to object to short reads.

1. Without `dd`, first run `sudo -s` to get a root shell:

   ```
    gzip </dev/sda2 >/media/mint/Data/_Fsarchiver/MintV1.img.gz
    gunzip </media/mint/Data/_Fsarchiver/MintV1.img.gz >/dev/sda2
   ```

   Your `zstd` commands look entirely plausible, but just omit `dd` and read/write the device directly as root. (My version doesn't understand your `T6` so I've omitted that here.)

   ```
    zstd -16v </dev/sda2 >/media/mint/Data/_Fsarchiver/MintV1.zst    
    zstdcat -v /media/mint/Data/_Fsarchiver/MintV1.zst >/dev/sda2
   ```
2. With `dd`, either prefix the `dd` with `sudo` or use `sudo -s` to get a root shell:

   ```
    dd bs=1M iflag=fullblock if=/dev/sda2 status=progress | gzip >/media/mint/Data/_Fsarchiver/MintV1.img.gz
    gzcat /media/mint/Data/_Fsarchiver/MintV1.img.gz | dd bs=1M iflag=fullblock of=/dev/sda2 status=progress

    dd bs=1M iflag=fullblock if=/dev/sda2 status=progress | zstd -16v >/media/mint/Data/_Fsarchiver/MintV1.img.zst
    zstdcat /media/mint/Data/_Fsarchiver/MintV1.img.zst | dd bs=1M iflag=fullblock of=/dev/sda2 status=progress
   ```
3. With `pv` instead of `dd`. Use `sudo -s` beforehand to get a root shell:

   ```
    pv /dev/sda2 | gzip >/media/mint/Data/_Fsarchiver/MintV1.img.gz
    gzcat /media/mint/Data/_Fsarchiver/MintV1.img.gz | pv >/dev/sda2

    pv /dev/sda2 | zstd -16 >/media/mint/Data/_Fsarchiver/MintV1.img.zst
    zstdzcat /media/mint/Data/_Fsarchiver/MintV1.img.zst | pv >/dev/sda2
   ```

   Also see [Syntax When Combining dd and pv](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/195555/100397)

As always, to read with elevated permissions change `command <source` to `sudo cat source | command`, and to write with elevated permissions replace `command >target` with `command | sudo tee target >/dev/null`.

Comment: The different variations are much appreciated.The `fullblock` flag is interesting. I take it that `dd`'s implementation tries to "be smart" and do clever speed tricks or something. Could you perhaps share some specifics if you know them?

Comment: @JonathanKomar without `fullblock`, `dd` will read and process short blocks (i.e. if you've asked for 1MB but only 500KB was available, that's what you'll get). If the next read returns zero bytes (because none is yet available from the source) it will be considered an EOF marker and reading will end. On Linux-based systems use `cat` instead of `dd` and all will be good

Answer (score 3):

`zstd` supports same commands and pipe capabilities as `gzip`,
so if the set of commands works with `gzip`, it will work with `zstd` too.

As a minor comment, note that several command flags on the decompression side are redundant: `zstd -dvc` would be enough and work the same, since `-f` and `-T6` are not useful for this scenario (though thankfully they also don't hurt).